# How to check whether a record exists before inserting

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6 Final and MySQL 5.5.37.

Suppose I have two tables `Book` and `Words` and some code that parses the words in the book and adds them to the `Words` table. There will certainly be words that appear in more than one book. However, I don't want a new entry for a word if it is already in the database. The only question is if Hibernate is smart enough to have some sort of functionality for this?

There are a couple of solutions, but none of them is pretty:

1. Check before creating the any `Word` object if there is already one like it in the database. Horrible for performance.
2. Catch the exception that is thrown when trying to insert a duplicate and handle that. Horrible practice.
3. Have some sort of static index of the words in the database, which is updated periodically, and search for the word in the list. Maybe slightly faster, but still horrible in terms of performance and memory.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: While I understand the dislike of using exception handling as a logic feature, this instance is perfectly acceptable to do so, and #2 is your best bet. In this case you'd be leveraging the functionality of the unique index in your Words table, and ignoring any exception that it threw.

Comment: That is what I would be tempted to do as well, but I am using a DAO to save all my objects in the database. This means that I am sharing a single class for common DB operations, which in turn means that I would have to write a special case for on specific case in a general class. Somehow this seems very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. From client (Hibernate) see if record exists, if not insert (could be subject to race condition)
2. Try to insert record, handle the error. You say this is bad practice, but I'd say it is good practice.
3. Put a trigger in the database and just skip the insert if the record exists

I would go with #2